# When $B$-modules $M$ and $M_A \otimes_A B$ are isomorphic?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $\varphi:A \to B$ a ring map and $M$ a (right)-$B$-module. We can associate to $M$ by restriction along $\varphi$ the (right)-$A$ module $M_A$, where the $A$-multiplication is given by $m \cdot a := m \cdot \varphi(a)$. Let $N:= M_A \otimes_A B$. $N$ is by construction an $B$ module.

Is there a sufficient & neccessary characterization on $A$ and $B$ known when $M =N$ as (right)-$B$-modules?

If $\varphi:A \to B:=A/I \cdot A$ is quotient for some ideal $I$ of $A$, then the $M_A$ 'not forgets' the $B$-module structure and then $M=N$ holds. Is this the only case?

I expect that this is a neccessary and sufficient condition, because it feels that if $\varphi$ is not surjective, $M_A \otimes_A B$ 'forgets' the action on $M$ by elements in $B$ not in the image. But I not know how to prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the question you're asking is when the natural map $M \otimes_A B \to M$ is an isomorphism (note that this is slightly stronger than just asking that the two be abstractly isomorphic), the answer is that this happens for all $M$ iff it happens in the special case that $M = B$ (since both the source and the target, as a functor of $M$, preserve colimits), meaning iff the multiplication map

$$B \otimes_A B \to B$$

is an isomorphism.

If $A$ and $B$ are both commutative, then it's an exercise to check that this condition is equivalent to the map $f : A \to B$ being an epimorphism in the category of commutative rings. This happens, for example, if $f$ is surjective, but also if $f$ is a localization, e.g. the map $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Q}$. I don't know the precise characterization in general (but see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/109/what-do-epimorphisms-of-commutative-rings-look-like) about epimorphisms of commutative rings); in the special case that $A = \mathbb{Z}$ rings $B$ with this property are called **solid rings** and they were [classified by Bousfield and Kan](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95160/solid-rings-and-tor).

I don't know what happens in the noncommutative case. An easy special case is that if $A = k$ is a field and $B$ is finite-dimensional over $k$ then by a simple dimension count the multiplication map $B \otimes_k B \to B$ can't be an isomorphism unless $\dim_k B = 1$, meaning that $B = k$. Maybe one can say something more generally about the case that $B$ is flat over $A$, I don't know.

Comment: yes, I'm asked about when $M_A \otimes_A B \to M$ is isomorphism as $B$-modules (by 'abstractly isomorphic' you mean as Abelian groups, right?). So you claim that this map is iso as $B$-mod iff $M=B$. I'm not sure. Consider the most trivial case that $A=B$ and $\varphi=id_A$. Then the about trivially holds for any $B$-module $M$. Or do I missing your point?

Comment: @user7391733: He's saying that the map is an isomorphism for all $B$-modules iff it is an isomorphism for the specific $B$-module $M=B$.

Comment: @user7391733: by "abstractly isomorphic" I mean there is some collection of $B$-module isomorphisms not necessarily given by the multiplication map. My claim is that the multiplication map is an isomorphism for all $M$ iff it's an isomorphism for the specific case $M = B$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan When you say that you don't know what happens in the noncommutative case, I'm not sure exactly what you're claiming not to know, but the connection with epimorphisms is the same: a ring homomorphism $A\to B$ is an epimorphism in the category of rings iff the multiplication map $B\otimes_AB\to B$ is an isomorphism (of $B$-bimodules, or, equivalently, of abelian groups).

Comment: oh sorry, I just misread this sentence, thank you.

Comment: @Jeremy: oh, interesting. In the commutative case this is a special case of a more general fact about pushouts, so in the noncommutative case the corresponding result involves the amalgamated free product $B \ast_A B \to B$. If it's still true for the tensor product then I don't know how to prove it off the top of my head; can you briefly indicate the argument?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Proofs I've seen prove the equivalence of several conditions on $f:A\to B$, including these two. Others are: (i) $b\otimes 1=1\otimes b\in B\otimes_AB$ for all $b\in B$, (ii) the map $B\to B\otimes_AB$ given by $b\mapsto b\otimes1$ is an isomorphism, (iii) restriction $\operatorname{Mod}B\to\operatorname{Mod}A$ is fully faithful. But I don't remember offhand what the geodesic is in either direction between "epimorphism" and "multiplication map is an isomorphism".

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Prop 1.1 of [this paper of Silver](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0021869367900671) gives a quite short proof, using a clever construction for the harder direction of "epimorphism" implies "multiplication map is an isomorphism".